# Using DLLs in Cython project

Tags: dll, cython

I have a C++ project (lets call it base.cpp) using Armadillo library (that needs libs and dlls for BLAS and LAPACK libraries). I want to import function from this C++ project via Cython by my another python project (main.py). I am using setup.py (including all .cpp, .h and .lib files) for building the .pyd file (call it test.pyd). The building of test.pyd file is succesfull, however when I run my main.py file, during the part of importing function from test  "ImportError:DLL Load failed: The specified module cannot be found" is raised. The Cython uses MSVC 2014 compiler. I have checked the directories where Windows looks for DLL files (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), but when I tried inserting there my dll files, nothing changed. My test.pyx file looks like this:

```
cdef extern from "base.h":
    void printer()

def printer_wrapper():
    printer()
```

where the function printer is just a function defined in base.cpp computing eigenvalues of a matrix. The main.py is just:

```
from test import printer_wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printer_wrapper()
```

Do you have any suggestions where I might put my dll files in order to be found during the main.py runtime?

Comment: I believe you specify link to the dll file in setup.py

Comment: I have tried adding the directory containg the dll files under runtime_library_dirs in Extension class. However, when compiling setup.py, an error: "warning: I dont know what to do with runtime_library_dirs... error: dont know how to set runtime library search path for MSVC" was raised.